# iOS4 SDK and iPod touch 1st gen

Tags: ios4, ipod-touch, iphone-sdk-2.2.1

i've an app that is compiled with iOS4 SDK.
i'd like to test on an ipod touch 1st gen (OS2.2.1)
I've set the deployment target to OS2.0 and Base SDK to 4.0.1

BUT

organizer tells me :

The version of iPhone OS on “iPod” is too old for use with this version of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below.

OS Installed on iPod
2.2.1 (5H11)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
4.0.1
4.0
3.2.1 (7B405)
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

From what i understood (correct me if i'm wrong), apple now requires app compiled with ios4 so theses apps can run on ipodtouch 1st Gen ???

am i missing something?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you can use anything from 3.0 higher. iPod touch 1G devices can use iOS 3 and iOS 3.1, so you should perform an upgrade on your device before using it with the iOS SDK.